# DataGrid won't display data after refresh if ObservableCollection is null at startup

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

Hopefully I can make this clear.  I have a DataGrid

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CanUserAddRows="False"
            CanUserDeleteRows="False"
            ItemsSource="{Binding projectEntriesForEmployee}">
```

bound to an

```
    public ObservableCollection<ProjectEntry> projectEntriesForEmployee { 
        get { return (ObservableCollection<ProjectEntry>)GetValue(projectEntriesForEmployeeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(projectEntriesForEmployeeProperty, value); }
    }
    public DependencyProperty projectEntriesForEmployeeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("projectEntriesForEmployee", typeof(ObservableCollection<ProjectEntry>), typeof(MainWindowVC));
```

If I set projectEntriesForEmployee before I load my UserControl (which I did to debug), my rows show properly in the DataGrid.  If however, projectEntriesForEmployee is null when the UserControl loads, when I set projectEntriesForEmployee to a valid ObservableCollection with items in the list (based on an event), no rows show on the DataGrid.  What could be going on?

Edit:
I've tried

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(projectEntriesForEmployee).Refresh();
```

but no joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone.  I've answered my own question, as it turns out that the problem was the Dependency Property Owner Type.  I had it as MainWindowVC.  It should have been TimeEntryVC.  As soon as I changed that, I commented out the resetting the ItemsSource in the Controller class, and everything worked as it should.  So @Tim, you're right that the Binding system takes care of things; I just told it to look for the property in the wrong class.  Thanks all regardless, as I understand better what's going on behind the scenes now than I did before.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's going on, but I would try using [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to drill into the DataGrid and make sure that, after you update `projectEntriesForEmployeeProperty` the `DataContext` of the `DataGrid` is still set to the appropriate object and to verify the binding on `ItemsSource`. If there are any binding errors, Snoop will show them and it'll also let you drill into the object and see the full binding expression. Just a suggestion.

Comment: I'll check Snoop out as well.  I need something to help me see what's going on with the XAML bindings, etc.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

When your control loads, both your OC, and your DataGrid's ItemsSource both point to the same thing: a null piece of memory.

Some time later, your initialize your OC to a collection.  Now your OC holds a collection, but your DataGrid's ItemSource still points to the same null piece of memory.

Can you not just initialize your OC in your control's constructor?

**EDIT**

I'm not a WPF guru, so there might be a reason to do this, but why are you setting your ObservableCollection as a dependency property?  If all your doing is binding it to your DataGrid's ItemsSource, a regular, vanilla C# property will work fine, and still provide you all of the automatic updates that occur when you add to, or remove from the collection.

Comment: I can't initialize it in the constructor, but the fact that they're not pointing to the same memory seems to be the problem.  I thought Binding would essentially point the datagrid and the OC to the same memory; obviously not.  I reset the ItemsSource property of the datagrid in my Controller class after getting the OC and voila, I have rows in my datagrid.  Thanks!

Comment: Re my previous comment, I just realized how dumb that is.  Obviously if the OC is null, it isn't pointing anywhere!  D'Oh!

Comment: There's not a clear way to explain why they don't point to the same place in memory after you init your OC.  In programming this is taught by imagining that when you say ItemsSource={Binding X} and arrow gets drawn from your grids ItemsSource to the same place in memory that X points to.  Now X, and your grids ItemsSource point to the same place.  Later, when you say X = new ...(); all youve done is changed the X's arrow to point some place new.  Your grid's ItemsSource still points to the same place.  I hope that's clear.

Comment: But the real question is why you can't init in your constructor.  As I mentioned in my answer, you can probably kill your dependency property altogether and just use a POCO property.  If all you're doing is binding to an ItemsSource, it'll work just as well

Comment: the ObservableCollection will notify the binding system when it gets added to or removed from, but it won't notify the system when it gets changed from null or to a completely different OC object. So that's why he needs it to be a DependencyProperty (or at least needs to implement INPC).

Comment: @Adam Rackis - I don't think your arrows explanation applies when you're talking about Bindings. The ItemsSource doesn't point to anything. There's just a binding added to the binding system that references both the ItemsSource property, the DataContext and the PropertyPath (in this case projectEntriesForEmployeeProperty). It's not like memory references in normal varaibles.

Comment: If what you're saying is true, then why did initializing the collection ahead of time (for debugging) solve his problem?  It sounds like it was wired up correctly, except that when he re-assigned his OC (from null to a collection) the grid didn't figure it out.  When it was initialized ahead of time, everything worked fine.

Comment: @Adam Obviously I'm not a WPF guru either ;-)).  I'll try that.  Thanks.

Comment: @Tim @Adam Sorry everyone.  I've changed this from answering the question, as it turns out that the problem was the Dependency Property Owner Type. I had it as MainWindowVC. It should have been TimeEntryVC.  As soon as I changed that, I commented out the reseting the ItemsSource in the Controller class, and everything worked as it should.  The Binding system takes care of things; I just told it to look for the property in the wrong class.  Thanks all, as I understand better what's going on behind the scenes now than I did before.  I post an answer later.

Comment: @Adam - well, that's why :) I'm 99% confident in what I said. It's the whole point of bindings as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Yep.  Tim was right; the dependency property was broken.  +1 to you sir.